# Multiplication Law for Order on Integers

Tags: equivalence-relations, integers, natural-numbers, ordered-rings

I'm using the following definitiosn for addition $+$, multiplication $\cdot$, and the relation $\preceq$ on the set of integers:
\begin{align*}\tag{I}
[(a,b)]+[(c,d)]&:=[(a+c,b+d)]
\\
\tag{II}
[(a,b)]\cdot [(c,d)]&:=[(ac+bd,ad+bc)].
\\
\tag{III}
[(a,b)]\preceq [(c,d)]&:\Leftrightarrow a+d\leq b+c
\end{align*}

I already proved that for all natural numbers $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that
\begin{align*}\tag{IV}
a\leq b\Leftrightarrow ac\leq bc.
\end{align*}

Now I want to show that for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $z>0$ we have that
\begin{align*}
x\preceq y\Leftrightarrow xz\preceq yz.
\end{align*}

I tried the following approach: Let $x=[(a,b)], y=[(c,d)]$, and $z=[(e,f)]$. From Definition (III) we have
\begin{align*}
[(a,b)]\preceq [(c,d)]\Leftrightarrow a+d\leq b+c.
\end{align*}
From (IV) we know that there exists some $u\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align*}\tag{V}
a+d\leq b+c\Leftrightarrow (a+d)\cdot u\leq (b+c)\cdot u.
\end{align*}

At this point I got stuck, so I tried to start with the other side of the equivalence I'm trying to prove, i.e.
\begin{align*}\tag{VI}
[(a,b)]\cdot[(e,f)]\preceq [(c,d)]\cdot[(e,f)].
\end{align*}

From (II) we have that
\begin{align*}
[(a,b)]\cdot[(e,f)]=[(ae+bf,af+be)]
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
[(c,d)]\cdot[(e,f)]=[(ce+df,cf+de)].
\end{align*}
Using this, equation (VI) becomes
\begin{align*}
[(ae+bf,af+be)]\preceq [(ce+df,cf+de)].
\end{align*}

Using (III) then gives us
\begin{align*}\tag{VII}
(ae+bf)+(cf+de)\leq (af+be)+(ce+df).
\end{align*}

At this point I'm stuck again. I was hoping to somehow link equations (V) and (VII) but that doesn't seem to work out. So I assume my approach was wrong, does anyone have an idea how to make this proof work?

Comment: I'm not sure but perhaps you can show there exists $w$ such that $x+w>0 $ and $y+w>0. $ And also show $\forall p,q,r\in\Bbb Z\,(p\le q\iff p+r\le q+r)$....You have $\forall a,b,c\in\Bbb N\,(a\le b\iff ac\le bc).$ So with $x+w=a$ and $y+w=b$ and $0<z=c,$ we have $xz\le yz\iff xz+wz\le yz+wz\iff ac\le bc\iff a\le b\iff x+w\le y+w\iff x\le y.$

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove (VI). Intuitively, that is $(a-b)·(e-f) \preceq (c-d)·(e-f)$. You are intuitively given $(e-f) \succ (0-0)$, which implies $e+0 > f+0$. So let $g∈ℕ$ such that $e = f+g$. You are also intuitively given $(a-b) \preceq (c-d)$, which implies $a+d ≤ b+c$. So now multiply by $g$. You get $(a+d)·g ≤ (b+c)·g$. Intuitively replace $g$ by $e-f$. You cannot literally do that since you don't have subtraction, but you can simulate it by adding the appropriate things to both sides. For example, to replace the first $g$ you add $(a+d)·f$ to both sides. Do the same for the second $g$ and you should get (VII) as desired.